# Finding maximum volume

Tags: calculus

A box has corner (0,0,0) and all edges parallel to the axes. If the opposite corner (x,y,z) is on the plane $$ 3x+2y+z=1 $$, what position gives maximum volume? Show first that the problem maximizes 
$$
xy-3x^2y-2xy^2
$$

Can somebody please explain how this should be solved?

Comment: Are you having trouble seeing where the $xy-3x^2y-2xy^2$ comes from? or trouble seeing how to maximize $xy-3x^2y-2xy^2$? or both?

Comment: Both. I have a clue on how to maximize, I am thinking of taking the second partial derivatives, but I am definitely not sure what to do with it.

Comment: By the way, unless you add some condition, like $(x,y,z)$ being in the first quadrant, there's no maximum. You could have $x$ be large and positive, $y=-x$, $z=1-x$, and volume $x^3-x^2$, unbounded as a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of the problem, we have each edge parallel to an axis, one corner at $(0,0,0)$ and one corner at $(x,y,z)$. This means that we can think about the sides of the box each having length $x$, $y$, and $z$. This gives us an area function $A(x,y,z)=xyz$.

We know that the corner $(x,y,z)$ is on the plane defined by $3x+2y+z=1$. If we solve this equation for $z$, we have $z=1-3x-2y$. We can the substitute this into our area function and have $$A(x,y,z)=xy(1-3x-2y)=xy-3x^2y-2xy^2.$$

Now, we need to maximize this function. To get started, we need to take partial derivatives of $A$ with respect to both $x$ and $y$. Please ask if you need help with this part.

Comment: Okay, let me try to go with this, and return when I have something new. Thanks!

Comment: okay, I have this now: $ f_x = y-6xy - 2y^2 $, $ f_y = x-3x^2-4xy $, $ f_{xx} = -6y $, $ f_{yy} = -4x $ and $ f_{xy} = 1-6x-4y $. Would the next step be to set $ f_x = 0 $ and $ f_y = 0 $ ?

Comment: Absolutely! The key here is to remember that you need to find values of $x$ and $y$ that make **both** $f_x$ and $f_y$ equal to zero. (You should end up with 4 points, but think about the boxes these points will make and see if they make sense). After this, you will need to use second partials to make sure you have a maximum. Finally, as Gerry mentions above (and I failed to write down) you will only have a maximum for $x>0, y>0, z>0$.

Comment: Could you give me a hint on solving the equations. What I got: $ y-6xy-2y^2 = x-3x^2+2xy \Rightarrow y-2y^2 = x-3x^2+2xy $

Comment: So you want to factor and compare. You can factor an $x$ out of $f_y$ and $y$ out of $f_x$ so you have $f_x = y(1-6x-2y)$ and $f_y=x(1-3x - 4y)$. Now you will need values of $x$ and $y$ that make both $f_x$ and $f_y$ zero. We continue matching up one factor from each equation with a factor from the other. That is, we have $y=0,x=0$.... $y=0, 1-3x-4y=0$, ... $1-6x-2y=0, x=0$ and $1-6x-2y=0, 1-3x-4y=0$. Solving each of these will result in 4 points to check for minimum, maximums and saddles using the second derivative test.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. I can see that $ x=0$ and $y=0$ satisfy the equations, but how can you get the equations $1-3x-4y=0$? Dont you need the $x(1-3x-4y$ that means the x before the parenthesis?

Comment: If $x=0$ or $1-3x-4y=0$ then when we multiply we will have $f_y=0$.  Consider the point $(\frac{1}{3} , 0)$. Then we have $f_x = 0$ as $y=0$ and we have $f_y=\frac{1}{3}(1-3\frac{1}{3}-4\cdot 0) = 0$. Thus $(\frac{1}{3} , 0)$ is a critical point.

Comment: But three of these critical points can be rejected out of hand, since setting $ \ x = 0 \ $ or $ \ y = 0 \ $ (or both) produces a "box" with zero volume (and thus _cannot_ be maxima of the volume function).  The only physically meaningful solution for this problem is the single critical point with $ \ x, y, \text{and} \ z \ $ all non-zero, found from solving simultaneously the equations $ \ 6x + 2y = 1 \ $ and $ \ 3x + 4y = 1 \ $ .

Answer (score 0):

You want to maximize $|xyz|$ w.r.t. constraint $3x+2y+z=1.$  The hint given in the problem is eliminating variable $z.$

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the arithmetic mean/geometric mean inequality? This immediately gives $ 3x = 2y = z $ as the unique absolute maximum of $ xyz $ over positive values of x, y and z, with the given constraint.